# Установка образа Windows на ноутбук Apple 2018 года

Tags: windows, apple, ос

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется ноутбук Apple Macbook Pro 2018 года, на него требуется установить образ windows 8.1. Образ windows собирается через sccm, появился затык при установке образа на сам ноутбук, он видит флешку, но через Diskpart не отображается сам диск который находится в ноуте следовательно при установке выдается ошибку 8000ffff.
Понимаю возможно проблема кроется в недостатке драйверов в загрузочном образе, перепробовал разные вариации с драйвером и результата это не дало.

Может тут найдутся знающие люди или кто сталкивался с подобным и дадут совет как решить проблему заливки образа ?

**p.s** Образ Windows 8.1 требуется залить чисто без использования bootCamp. На старые ноутбуки Apple заливка происходит успешна, ноутбуки 2014-2015 года.